# OpenCl - Global and local size - differences and why increasing local size only sometimes is noticable?

Tags: multithreading, opencl, gpgpu

I wrote 2 OpenCl programs that are multiplatform and multidevices.
First is Integral and second Matrix-Matrix multiplication.
I found out that manipulating with global work size and making it bigger to some absurdly big numbers like 2^28 is slowing my program (while local size is 1)
and I kind of can self explain that to me, because probably GPU puts every thread that it has and as global size is so big, another threads are queued and waiting for previous one to finish their job and it is slowing the computing down.
But in matrix multiplication I was able to set local size to 1024 (my max) and it went so fast, like from 130 seconds of computing to about 6 seconds.
But in Integral I did the same, but increasing local size doesn't change anything in terms of time spent on computing.
When I was learning OpenCl I didn't understand what is that global and local size, now I understand that global size number is just number of threads that will execute kernel code, which means if global size is 4 000, kernel code will be executed 4 000 times. But I still don't understand what is local size and why sometimes it make a difference and sometimes not, can someone explain "local size" definition to me? In a simple words.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** long story short:

integral ==> data re-use = 1 ==> memory intensive

matrix multiplication ==> data re-use = n ==> cache intensive(or local memory)

memory intensive ==> even 3-5 threads per compute unit fills all memory request slots of gpu so doesn't matter if there are 40-50 or 900-1000 per compute unit. They all queued until memory controllers serve all requests. The operations are serialized.

cache intensive ==> cache hit ratio high ==> more compute to memory ratio

more threads per group ==> more data re-use ==> better cache usage ==> performance when only code is cache intensive

---

In integral kernel, you are using variables once or a few times at most so it has no visible effect on kernel execution time.

In matrix multiplication, each data block is used N times. If they are in local memory, it is bottlenecked by local memory bandwidth. If it is in global memory, it is bottlenecked by cache (maybe L2) bandwidth. If local memory is much faster than cache, it will be visible on timings of benchmark.

Having billions of threads makes thread dispacthing/issuing/fetching bottleneck
visible on timings if each thread is doing just a few add and multiply operations.

Answer for matrix multiplication vs integral is **data re-use ratio**.

Maybe size of cache is important too. If it is large enough and high-bandwidth, then it may not matter if you use local memory or not. For example, if AMD's vega architecture has 256MB L2 cache, then it should have similar performance to local memory version (if cache bandwidth is also comparable to local memory)

```
Local thread number(nLocal): max number of threads that share same local memory.

Global thread number(nGlobal): max number of threads.

Max wavefront threads = k * nLocal 
// k is a dynamic factor depending on 
// free resources per compute unit.  

nGlobal = m * nLocal 
// so global number is an exact multiple of local number 
// but may not be exact ultiple of wavefront thread number
```

if per thread local mem usage increases, k decreases
   if per thread local mem usage increases, you should decrease nLocal
   if nLocal < numCoresPerComputeUnit, it is suboptimal

local threads consume register file of their compute unit
   local threads share local memory and L1 of their compute unit
   compute units share L2,constant memory(and texture memory?)
   L2 is tied to video ram (at least for disrete gpus)

but architecture changes, AMD's vega for example, showing L1 is on globally shared position and whole threads become one client of L2 through a shared L1 just ike graphics pipeline part.

Size of local memory is fixed and shared by local threads so if they use more per thread, you should decrease local thread number or it will spill to global memory and get very slow or return errors through opencl api.

Generally it is 64kB per compute unit so you can use 4kB per thread if nLocal is 16.

Comment: I am using only global memory, no __local anywhere. For ntegral I set dx = 0.0001 and range for computing is 0-66536 so if there is only 1 GPU computing it, it will have to do 655360000 operations, but I impletemented it that way: if you increase global size, every thread gets smaller piece to compute. But still it is a lot of operations, so why it has ABSOLUTELY no impact when I increase local size? For example: 0-65539 range and dx = 0.0001 and on 1 GPU it computes 133 seconds for local size 1, for local size 1024 (my max) it is still 133 seconds. Is it really normal?

Comment: What is your gpu? Brand, series, model, segment, stepping.

Comment: I have access to supercomputer's cluster with 2x Nvidia Tesla k40xl [specification](http://www.nvidia.pl/content/tesla/pdf/NVIDIA-Tesla-Kepler-Family-Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: it has 15 smx so local=1 means it will have 15 memory requests per cycle and with wavefronts(multiple threads per core) it can have 30 - 90 memory requests maybe. This means  at least 30 x 4(bytes per float) x 4 (request size) = 480 bytes per clock cycle. This is rounded to half a kB per cycle = half a terabyte per 1 giga cycle (or nearly one second) which is way over the memory capability of k40 so memory is bottleneck when kernel is memory intensive. So increasing local size just increases queue size of memory requests while memory data fetch is always busy, throughput is same always.

Comment: Memory intensive = pci-e bridge can be a bottleneck too, if host needs to get results back.

Comment: I dont know if I understand it correctly, could you please explain to me what exactly local size represent? As I know global size is saying just how many threads will execute kernel, but local size? what is it in a simple words? And I still dont understand why local increase does not affect integral even slightly but matrix multip. affects A LOT. in both we have the same type of operation, just multiplication and addition and in both we have a lot of iteration. Only difference I see is that I used 2D global size and local for matrix mul, I mean local[0] and local[1] both = 32 so its 1024

Comment: local group size is number of threads sharing same local memory per compute unit(multiprocessor). Also there are multiple groups in-flight in same compute unit. Each thread requests memory operation which is queued when it is not available. Even single thread per group fills all request slots of a gpu so it doesn't matter how many threads per group is selected, ofcourse only when kernel is memory intensive as in integral. Matrix multiplication re-uses data so it is more like cache intensive unless you use local memory.

Comment: So just to be clear, when we have algorithm like matrix multiplication local work size matter because it is constantly using the same data to multiply rows and columns and that is why max local size in that algorithm decreases the execution time yes? and for integral when we use new data with every iteration it does not matter because there is no point of threads having shared memory in this case yes? and that is why in integral making localsize big dont change anything and in matrix multiplication it does yes? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Gzyniu yes,yes,yes(only for cpu could it change a bit),yes

Comment: I have another question regarding that differences between changing local size in two algorithms. I saw few posts on stack where people were telling that if you dont use __local variables and do not use get_local_id () local size doesnt affect anything and this is exactly my scenario. I dont use it but see differences. Are they right?

Comment: @Gzyniu if each compute unit has more than 1 cores and you pick local=1 then you use only 1 core per compute unit whiich is suboptimal computationally but best for memory

Comment: Ok but if I use one core per compute unit as you said with local 1 and I use every core I got per compute unit with local 1024 which is my max and execution times are the same then is it really normal? I dont use any __local and get_local_id() so even if integral is not reusing data, number of cores per compute unit doesnt matter?

Comment: @Gzyniu if data is used only once, doesn't matter if it is from local memory or global memory but if compute part is heavy, as many cores as possible sould be used. Total latency or throughput is dependent on memory access latecies and compute latencies. For example, square root takes longer than multiplication but if it fetches 1kB just for a square root, it wiill be hidden by memory latency

Comment: 3 answers before, you told (only for cpu could it change a bit) and now, when I run integral for CPU, changing local size matter, and when local size = 1 integral is executing for about 70 seconds, and when local is on its max (4096) it is 10 seconds now. Is it that what you wanted to say? why on cpu it matters and on GPU not?

Comment: @Gzyniu cpu, unlike a gpu, doesn't have a directly controllable/addressable cache and also cpu's closest-to-core cache is only shared by 1 core (or maybe 2 hardware threads) maximum. So it is much better at serially given work, not threadedly parallel work (of course talking for single core here). When you increase local size, it performs those one by one, works like a streaming processor but when local size = 1 then it first finishes first group, add some overhead of thread group scheduling, then move on to next thread group, performance loss. But cpu lose bad with synchronizations/barriers

Comment: @Gzyniu try with barrier function and compare with both cases to check which one is slower now  (for cpu). Instead of making local=1, make single thread process 4096 elements of data(with much less global size), which should have much better performance then local=4096.